# How to hide a <li> item in html and make it not occupy any space?

Tags: html, hidden

I have an html list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

How can I hide a li item and make it not occupy any space? Let's say, I need the first li item (coffee) to be invisible, so the result will contain only Tea and Milk. I used css (or style="visibility: hidden"), but it still occupies some space.

=======

Note: the first li is just some template used to create the other li items. The template li is generated during the run time, and that's why I need to hide it. I remove it eventually after generating the other li items (Tea and Milk), but before I generate Tea and Milk, Coffee is still visible.

============

**Thanks. Answer is style="display:none"**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a class and apply it to elements which you wish to hide.  You can do it when you generate markup or add the class to each element using a selector, like jquery

```css
.hide{
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="hide">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

In css you want (or some similar selector)

```
ul > li:first { display: none; }
```

Or if you prefer directly placing the css definition on the element itself

```
<ul>
 <li style="display:none;">Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Another common practice is to simply create a style applied by a class if you wish to apply this style

```
<style> .nodisplay { display: none; } </style>
<ul>
 <li class="nodisplay">Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Using `display:none;` will remove the element from the flow of the page, and as a result there will be no blank space as can occur when using `visibility: hidden;`

> "Turns off the display of an element (it has no effect on layout); all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element did not exist.
>
> To render an element box's dimensions, yet have its contents be invisible, see the visibility property." [*display: none* <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:none;` instead.

That makes the element disappear and not take up any space.

Answer (score 2):

You could style it.

```
...
<li style="display:none;">
....
```

That should hide the element

Answer (score 1):

Just write this:

```
<ul class="groceries">
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>

.groceries {     
list-style: none;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can achieve this. The first one is to use CSS `display` property :

```
Sample.html
<ul>
  <li class="list-hidden-item">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>


Sample.css
.list-hidden-item { display: none; }
```

Another is to use HTML5 attribute `hidden`

```
Sample.html
<ul>
  <li hidden>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```